# Calling api in react with axios and search but don't know how to do it

Tags: reactjs, rest, axios, react-state-management, react-starter-kit

So here is the thing. I have the endpoint but don't know how to filter the response and list the result in the same way for every object.

I know this a very newbie intro question,  I appreciate any article that you guys think that can help.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import '../assets/styles/Shared.css';
import { MDBBtn } from 'mdbreact';
/////
import axios from 'axios';
import api from '../services/api';

class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="CallApi">
          <div className="container">
            <h1 className="logo"></h1>

            <h1 className="search">
              <input className="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search for vehicle" onClick={null} />
              <MDBBtn color="unique" rounded size="sm" type="submit" className="mr-auto">
                Pesquisar
              </MDBBtn>
              <h1 className="hometext">THE SEARCH FOR THE VEHICLES</h1>
            </h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

The data format is:

```
  {
    "id": "1",
    "title": "title 1",
    "model": "model 1",
    "brand": "brand 1",
    "year": 69,
    "color": 19,
    "km": 79,
    "price": 99
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

To work with the returned JSON, you can use the function [map()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp).

You should filter the data in your backend because load all the information in frontend could make your app slow, but you can the function [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```
  const search = () => {
    axios.get(`${YOUR_URL}`)
      .then(res => {
        return res.data
      })
  }

  return (
    <>
    {search().map((item) => {
      return(
        <h1>{ item.title }</h1>
        )
      })}
  </>
  )
```